# Auto login to LinkedIn

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization, social-network

I have installed HybridAuth module. I can login from my website using LinkedIn. But my question is, how can I login automatically into LinkedIn when I login from my website using LinkedIn login?

I have gone though various APIs but could not get proper information.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Opposite (auto-login if you already are logged to LinkedIn) should be possible, if you decided to trust LinkedIn. But why LinkedIn should trust you?

Comment: Thanks Molot for a reply. can you add this as an answer with some more information so that I can accept ?

Comment: Nope, that's only my guess and not my knowledge. If someone can do a bit of research, please do and post answer. If no, I'll try to elaborate... in about 8 hours from now, when I'll have more time. Not enough time now.

Answer (score 2):

Got something closely related to your case and I won't say this is not possible, you can have some workaround by following these threads:

[Login to Drupal using LinkedIn](https://www.drupal.org/node/824266)

This feature is not available right now, to login into Linkedin while using its credential on your site. But it seems that, this thread is in knowledge of Linkedin Officials as well and there may be some work is going on to provide you create app feature just like Facebook.

Here is something to elaborate the same:

http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/how-create-linkedin-application-tripit-or-slideshare

Answer (score 1):

This is only done with both website communicate each other. It means that your website and **linkedin** both assured each other **credential information** and surely linkedin cant trust your website so it is not possible